# Toggle multiple commands with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a menu button that both opens my menu and also triggers other commands at the same time.

When button is clicked, menu should open and background change to red.

When button is clicked again, menu should close and background change to green.

http://test.bsley.com/rest/menu3/

Any help would be much appreciated!

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'red') {
       alert("test");
    } else {
        $("#panel").slideDown("fast");
        $("body").css( "background-color", "red" );
    }
});
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="panel">Here is the menu</div> <div id="trigger">+ Menu</div>
```

Comment: Is the problem the fact that the menu cannot be closed and background colour changed to green?

Comment: @pablofiumara yes sir! Sorry for not including code at first guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this in click callback refer to button element, not body element.
try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").click(function() {
        var $btn = $(this);

        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            $('body').css("background-color", "green");
        } else {
            $('body').css("background-color", "red");
        }

        $('#panel').slideToggle('fast', function() {
            $btn.toggleClass('opened');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CthzA/6/

Answer (score 1):

Simple reason is that the css method isn't returning the same as you set it too, it's returning and rgb value rather than the string "red".

Here's what I would have done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").click(function() {
        if ( $('#panel').is(':visible') ) {
            $("#panel").slideUp("fast");
            $("body").css( "background-color", "white" );
        } else {
            $("#panel").slideDown("fast");
            $("body").css( "background-color", "red" );
        }
    });
 });
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/IhINuYu)

I'm not checking for the colour but whether the menu area is visible or not.  Read about the is method here: [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Also, it's worth mentioning you can just attach as many on event listeners to an element as you like - so you can do this and all of it will run when #trigger is clicked:

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function() { /*show/Hide the menu*/ })
$('#trigger').on('click', function() { /*change the background colour*/ })
$('#trigger').on('click', function() { /*do more stuff*/ })
```

Good luck getting it all working!

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CthzA/7/)

```
var i = 0;
$('#trigger').click(function () {
    var color;
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
        color = "red";
    } else {
        color = "green";
    }
    $('body').css('background-color', color);
    $('#panel').slideToggle();
});
```

References

http://api.jquery.com/css/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: This works but it removes the sliding animation. How can I keep this? Also, if I wanted to fade the background color from one to another?

Comment: @JeremyPaulBeasley check updated answer .My answer is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/F6qAT/):

HTML

```
<div id="panel">Here is the menu</div> <div id="trigger">+ Menu</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'red') {
       alert("test");
    } else {
        $("#panel").slideDown("fast");
        $("body").css( "background-color", "red" );
    }
});
    });  


var i = 0;
$('#trigger').click(function () {
    var color;
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
        color = "red";
    } else {
        color = "green";
    }
    $('body').css('background-color', color);
    $('#panel').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I added it here but the menu won't open back up now. http://test.bsley.com/rest/menu4/